# Recover a deleted amplify backend project

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have deleted my amplify backend project by mistake. I had only single environment. It deleted all related services. I would like to get back the amplify project which i have deleted.

I tried pushing the existing local folder through amplify push but it doesnt work.

Comment: Contact technical support. If you don't have support, then you're probably best out of luck.